# ggplot2 not detecting geom mapped with aes_string

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is what I'm having issues with:

```
library(ggplot2)
Name1 <- "example withspace"
df1 <- data.frame(x=1, y=2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=df1, mapping=aes_string(x="x", y="y", color=as.name(Name1)),
  size = 3) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = setNames("red", 
    as.name(Name1)))
```

When you run it, you get:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'example withspace' not found
```

How do I format the value in scale_color_manual so that it will recognize a layer with a space in the name?

I need to keep this format, since my actual code has multiple layers.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You don't have a variable in `df1` called `example withspace`, so there's nothing to map. You probably don't want variable names with spaces anyway; you'll have to use a million backticks to make them work. Add spaces by changing the labels.

Answer (score 0):

It is detecting the object 'Name1', but because you're using as.name, it's reading the contents of Name1 - 'Example Whitespace' and then parsing that as an object.

To use an object with whitespace, use `` markers around the object.

Your code is equivalent to

```
geom_point(data=df1, mapping=aes_string(x="x", y="y", color=`Example Whitespace`)),
```

But Example Whitespace isn't an object in your environment, so this should fail too?